# Need to upper all models

Tags: django, models, uppercase

I'm using this def to uppercase some data before sending it to the database, is working perfectly, the problem is that I need to do the same with all the data and they are 107 rows.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
      self.nombre_contacto_15 = self.nombre_contacto_15.upper()
      super(ExpedienteConsultaInicial, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

I believed that using all.upper will do it for all the model,  but I was wrong :)  I'm a Django Newbie.

models.py

```
class ExpedienteConsultaInicial(models.Model):
    #Inicia Campos Estudios Solicitados
    exam_de_lab_111 = models.ForeignKey(Servicios_laboratorios,    related_name='C1Lx',blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_de_solicitud_112 = models.DateField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_laboracion_113 = models.DateField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    observaciones= models.CharField(max_length=6000, null=True,blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.credencial_consultainicial

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.nombre_miembro_1 = self.nombre_miembro_1.upper()
    self.nombre_contacto_15 = self.nombre_contacto_15.upper()
    super(ExpedienteConsultaInicial, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean by 107 variables is that there are 107 rows in the database, you can open the Django shell with:

```
$ python manage.py shell
```

and from the Python shell import your database model:

```
>>> from myapp.models import MyModel
```

and run whatever you want on it:

```
>>> for o in MyModel.objects.all:
...  o.nombre_contacto_15 = o.nombre_contacto_15.upper()
...  o.save()
...
>>>
```